# Nested holes in Shapely Polygon

Tags: python, recursion, nested, gis, shapely

A Shapely Polygon has an exterior polygon, and any number of 'holes' or interior polygons (https://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#polygons).

Is there a Shapely object which represents a shape with an arbitrary number of nested holes? Like this:[image: Nested polygons.]

Comment: `MultiPolygon`?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the manual (https://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#collections-of-polygons), MultiPolygons are not valid if the polygons are inside each other. Furthermore, there the MultiPolygon class no has built-in support for notions such as nesting level, and would not know which parts of the collection were holes and which parts were filled.

However, if I had to create my own class representing a nested polygon, I would probably use a MultiPolygon as a container for each polygon.

Comment: I don't have Shapely here at the moment. But you can modify this example with two more lines to find out: https://toblerity.org/shapely/code/multipolygon.py

Answer (score 2):

The example you provided can be represented as a MultiPolygon made of two Polygons:

1. A Polygon with two holes
2. A Polygon without holes (the one inside the hole)